# Making 1 of 6 Variables true randomly in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, var

I am trying to make a one of a series of divs appear randomly with jquery along with it's navigation link(i.e. If services gets pick, the services link will unfade). I have found this code various times in various forms on this forum, and was wondering if and how I could adapt it to what I would want.

```
var services = $(random1, random2, random3).get()
            .sort(function(){return  Math.round(Math.random());}).slice(0,1)
        $(services)/*Conditions here*/;

var random1 = false;
var random2 = false;
var random3 = false;
```

This is a really bad example, I know. I am get lost on it. Any help would be greatly apprecaited, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: I did try to make an easier comparison earlier, but here is what I am actually working on. I tried to adapt the code from @pst.

```
    var v1 = "hello"
var v2 = "world"
var control = [
   function (v) { v1 = v },
   function (v) { v2 = v }
]

$.each(control, function (i, fn) {
   fn(false)
})



$("a#random-btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var trueIdx = Math.floor(control.length * Math.random())
    props[trueIdx](true)


        if (v1 === true){
                $("div#small-obstacles-contain a#1 span").stop().animate({opacity: 1,}, '100').animate({opacity: 0,}, '100');
                $("div#small-obstacles-contain a#2 span").stop().animate({opacity: 1,}, '100').animate({opacity: 0,}, '100');
        }   

        if (v2 === true){
                $("div#small-obstacles-contain a#3 span").stop().animate({opacity: 1,}, '100').animate({opacity: 0,}, '100');
                $("div#small-obstacles-contain a#4 span").stop().animate({opacity: 1,}, '100').animate({opacity: 0,}, '100');
        }

});
```

Comment: Please do not wrap objects that aren't DOM elements in jQuery objects. It's not what jQuery should be used for. You can do that with plain javascript and if you want the nice functional utilites have a look at [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). Besides that, `$(random1, random2, random3).get()` is the same as `[random1, random2, random3]` - so you aren't actually using jQuery since you wrap your vars and then unwrap them again. `$(services);` then does nothing at all since you throw away the return value.

Comment: I didn't add a return yet, I had it at the default `.show()`. It will most likely be a `.animation()`. Nevermind I want it to make the var true.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is really an X-Y problem, this address the title, but may miss "what is really desired at the end of the day". In any case, the concepts are somewhat adaptable.

---

I wouldn't use variables, but rather an an array/object.

Let's assume an object (so we can have different names used :-) and then a "control" sequence for which properties are eligible to be toggled:

```
var obj = {a: true, b: false, "3": false, hello: "world"} 
var control = ["a", "b", "3"]
// set all to false -- noet that $.each != $().each !!!
$.each(control, function (i, prop) {
  obj[prop] = false
})
// set one true
var trueIdx = Math.floor(control.length * Math.random())
obj[control[trueIdx]] = true
```

However, if variables were *really desired* for some reason then closures could be used (this could also be used to run arbitrary code for a particular binding):

```
var v1 = "hello"
var v2 = "world"
var control = [
   function (v) { v1 = v },
   function (v) { v2 = v }
]
// set all to false -- noet that $.each != $().each !!!
$.each(control, function (i, fn) {
   fn(false)
})
// set one true
var trueIdx = Math.floor(control.length * Math.random())
props[trueIdx](true)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: "happy obfuscating" I'd say ;-)

Comment: @zerkms If you think that's bad... ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Is right, trying to hide the demeanor of the code. Not due to security, I just wanted to make an easier comparsion. I am posting the code I am working on now.